# Jquery ajax in laravel 5.6

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

`$request->amount` is not working on a controller in Laravel. Why. What is my error?
Then I change like `$request->input('amount');` anyway it didn't work.

```
<script>

    function getMessage(product_id){
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type:'POST',
            url:'/getmsg/'+product_id,
            date: {
              amount: 4,
              buyed_price: 1200,
            },

            data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
            success:function(data){
                $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have not got any input yet. just I need send 4 as the amount to the controller. please look my code

Comment: i just read your mind and i saw you didn't name your input element

Comment: dd your $request and paste

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

in blade

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dm" />
```

in controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function method_name(Request $request){
    $text = $request->dm;
}
```

Comment: <script>

        function getMessage(product_id){
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                type:'POST',
                url:'/getmsg/'+product_id,
                date: {
                  amount: 4,
                  buyed_price: 1200,
                },

                data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#msg").html(data.msg);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

You have typo mistake in your code. your first date is wrong and second data is correct. You have to used data, not date.

```
<script>

    function getMessage(product_id){
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type:'POST',
            url:'/getmsg/'+product_id,
            data: {
              _token: <?php echo csrf_token() ?>, // this is optional cause you already added it header
              amount: 4,
              buyed_price: 1200,
            },
            success:function(data){
                $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[Read this](https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-55-jquery-ajax-request-example-from-scratch) article for more info.